# Finding the class name of a sibling element using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular8, angular-datatables

I need to know the class name of my angular material data table rows. Rows are as follow:

```
<tr class="scan-row mat-row ng-tns-c4-1 active ng-star-inserted scan-expanded-row">...</tr>
<tr class="scan-detail-row mat-row ng-tns-c4-1 ng-star-inserted">...</tr>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You've provided two `<tr>` elements of which there is only one identifying factor for each – their class. If you wish to get the class names of your table rows, you can use the vanilla JS functions [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp), which will return an array of of all table row elements, and [getAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp), which will return each element's class name.

```
var classes = document.getElementsByTagName("TR");
classes.foreach(function(item, index) {
    let className = item.getAttribute("class");
    // do something with className
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @possum_pendulum but the problem is that I can't use JS.

Comment: @BeatrizIC what do you mean by "know the class name of a _sibling_ element"? Edit your post with whatever Angular TS code you've tried to make this work with so we can have somewhere to start.